# Can I make c3.js chart responsive with gridister.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I have some chart of c3.js inside the gridister.js widgets. As I am resizing gridister.js widgets, I want to resize the chart also.

I tried below code to set c3.js charts responsive but it is not working

```
resize: {
enabled: true,
stop: function (event, ui, $widget) {
    var newDimensions = this.serialize($widget)[0];
    var height = newDimensions.size_y;
    var width = newDimensions.size_x;
    chart = d3.select('#chart_donut');

    //change the width of chart start
    d3.select("div#chart_donut")
    .append("div")
    .classed("svg-container", true) //container class to make it responsive
    .append("svg")
    //responsive SVG needs these 2 attributes and no width and height attr
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 600 400")
    //class to make it responsive
    .classed("svg-content-responsive", true);
    //chart.attr("height", targetWidth / aspect);


    var positions = JSON.stringify(gridster.serialize());

    // ajax call to update widget postions in the database
    $.post(
        "doc/ajax_postion_update", {
        products: positions,
        doc_id: doc_id
    },
        function (data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
    });
}
```

Please help me to make charts realizable on resize of gridister.js widget.

Comment: What happens if you call http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-resize method instead of manipulating svg?

Comment: in that chart and width should be same and i want a way like gridister has to increase reduce height and width